# Add facebook like button to sharepoint list item

Tags: list, list-item, like

**How can I add a facebook like button to a sharepoint list item in Sharepoint 2013?**

P.S: I'm intrested in adding a like button only to a list item, *not to the whole page*.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add OOTB SharePoint rating to a list. Go to the list > list settings > rating settings.

Set "Allow items in this list to be rated?" to Yes and choose between having "Likes" or "Star ratings".

[Enable users to rate content](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Enable-users-to-rate-content-fe6302dc-d521-4a56-99a6-133b63ee7afc)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I've made the settings but I can't make the rating column show on the main site page. It shows only the item in the list, without any other column. I tried changing the view but when I edit the view (Modify view) the other columns are displayed. When I navigate to the main site page where the list is used, the column disappears again. Can you help me please?

Comment: When you make changes in a listview and are displaying the lists/apps on a site/page, you have to edit the site/page and edit the list-webpart. Select the new view or the same you are using in the web part settings and apply to get any new / modified columns changes. :)

Comment: You mean I click Edit page, then select the web part, and when the menu appears there is some option regarding the columns shown? I can't seem to find it

Comment: See the picture i attached. Edit the page, and edit the web part settings. Choose the current view you want to have, and then press apply and save the page. This should update the current list view.